# Inserting space between two input fields on same line in an html form

Tags: html, css, web

I am trying to create a form using html and CSS. My form requires the first two input fields to be on the same line however I am struggling with spacing them out so that they are in line with the rest of the input fields of the form

Here is my code
Html:

```
<div class="contact-form">
  <div class="split-fields">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
    <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name">
  </div>

  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
  <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  .contact-form {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .contact-form input,
  .contact-form textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
  
  .contact-form textarea {
    height: 100px;
  }
  
  .contact-form button {
    background-color: #ff9700;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .contact-form button:hover {
    background-color: #ff7b25;
  }
  
  .split-fields {
    display: flex;
  }
```

What my output currently looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the below code:

```css
.contact-form {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.contact-form input,
.contact-form textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.contact-form textarea {
  height: 100px;
}

.contact-form button {
  background-color: #ff9700;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.contact-form button:hover {
  background-color: #ff7b25;
}

.split-fields {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-form">
  <div class="split-fields">
    <div class="first-name">
      <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
    </div>
    <div class="first-name">
      <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name">
    </div>
  </div>

  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
  <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try to follow this in my future answers.

Answer (score 0):

### Margin

You can add `#first_name {margin-right: 8px;}` but now you need to add `id="first_name"` in first name element.

---

### Posting

Instead of `<div class="contact-form">` use `<form class="contact-form" method="POST">`. Now it can be submitted to php code.

I hope that this will help.